# How do I repeat the last n changes in Vim?

Tags: vim, repeat

Doing `.` repeats the last change. Doing `2.` repeats the last change two times.

But imagine I want to repeat the change before the last one. How do I do it in Vim?

Comment: That seems to be a terriffic feature to request. (http://www.vim.org/sponsor/vote_results.php); I'd like to have 'time-machine' like after-the-fact macro recording

Answer (score 39):

Don't think you can, see `:help .` However, what you can do is to record a macro for your edits, you have a lot of registers to choose from `{0-9a-zA-Z"}` (uppercase to append).
Then use e.g. `@u` for edit 1, `@t` for edit 2 and so on.

Great tips about recording from [Best of VIM Tips](http://www.rayninfo.co.uk/vimtips.html)

```
" Recording (BEST TIP of ALL)
qq  # record to q
your complex series of commands
q   # end recording
@q to execute
@@ to Repeat
5@@ to Repeat 5 times
qQ@qq                             : Make an existing recording q recursive *N*
" editing a register/recording
"qp                               :display contents of register q (normal mode)
<ctrl-R>q                         :display contents of register q (insert mode)
" you can now see recording contents, edit as required
"qdd                              :put changed contacts back into q
@q                                :execute recording/register q
```

Have a look at these for more hints for repeating:

```
:&     last substitute
:%&    last substitute every line
:%&gic last substitute every line confirm
g%     normal mode repeat last substitute
g&     last substitute on all lines
@@     last recording
@:     last command-mode command
:!!    last :! command
:~     last substitute
:help repeating
```

Comment: yeah, i did know about macros. just wondering if there was a simpler way to do this. i'm still getting used to vim and macros are yet in my to learn/muscle train list. thanks anyway :)

Comment: The `.` command is neat because of shortness; and very useful for small cases where the macro would take more keystrokes than redoing the last two operations by hand. Though this is a good answer, it is not yet marked as right.

Answer (score 10):

I wrote [the RepeatLast.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4381) to address this exact requirement.  It provides a `5\.` key binding to repeat the last 5 changes (including movements) and `2\D` to drop/forget the last 2 actions.

It works by enabling macro recording *all the time*, which may not be desirable for everyone.  But if you can live with that, it works in 99% of use cases.

Latest version: https://github.com/joeytwiddle/RepeatLast.vim  (Please feedback!)

> Caveats:
>
> Please `:set ch=2` so that the first line of output won't be hidden by the "recording" message.
>
> The 1% of times it fails to work as intended are usually due to:
>
> 1. Difficulties triggering the CursorHold event slowly without losing
>      fast-repeated keystrokes
> 2. Undesirable recording of [Space] and
>      [Enter] keys when the user is responding to a prompt.

Training your `q` muscle to pre-emptively record macros might be a better approach in the long term.  ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Based on Fredrick Phil's answer, here is an example:

**Recording your macro**

The following shows how to record a macro to delete everything in and including a quoted string and store in register `d`. The command to delete a string is `da"`. So to store this command in macro register d we can simply do this:

```
qdda"q
```

Notice it starts and ends with a q. The second character is the register, in this case `d` for delete. But we could have given it any letter or number. The remaining characters `da"` is our command.

**Using our macro**

Now that our macro is recorded we can invoke it by using the @ symbol followed by the register:

```
@d
```

**Repeating the last macro command**

To use the most recently invoked macro command again:

```
@@
```

**Unrelated info:**

In this example, we used `da"` which stands for `delete a quoted string`. (If you instead wanted to delete everything `inside` the quoted string, but not the quotation marks themselves you can instead use `di"` instead.).

Answer (score 0):

### Record Your "Edits"

yes! you can do this in vim!

One of Vim's most useful features is its ability to record what you type for later playback. This is most useful for repeated jobs that cannot easily be done with <kbd>.</kbd>

To **start recording**

- press <kbd>q</kbd> in normal mode followed by a letter (<kbd>a</kbd> to <kbd>z</kbd>)

  - That starts recording keystrokes to the specified register. *Vim displays recording in the status line*
  - Type any normal mode commands, or enter insert mode and type text

To **stop recording**

- *ending in normal mode*, come to normal mode if you are not, and press <kbd>q</kbd>
- *ending in insert mode*, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, this will temporarily get you into normal mode, and then press <kbd>q</kbd>

To **playback your keystrokes/recording**

- press <kbd>@</kbd> followed by the letter previously chosen
- Typing <kbd>@@</kbd> repeats the last playback

***References***

- [Vim Fandom: Recording keys for repeated jobs](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Recording_keys_for_repeated_jobs)
- [Vim Fandom: Macros](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Macros)
- [Quora - How do you stop recording a Vim macro when in insert mode?](https://qr.ae/pGBIEG)